# How to get the values from array with object comma seperated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hi i am having a array where i am trying to get the value from it, And not able to get the value in object below:

```
let array= [
      "from 05:04 - to 09:41, train 342 SEK, wifi",
      "Restid 4:37 tim, 0 byten",
      "från",
      "fr.",
      "342",
      "SEK",
      "Företagspris",
      "2 klass, 2 klass Lugn, 1 klass",
      "Snabbtåg, X 2000, Tåg 522"
    ]
```

From above array i am trying to access like array[0][0] to get first value, but not getting the value, Is there any way to access the values like this, If i use array[0] i am getting 0th like this **from 05:04 - to 09:41, train 342 SEK, wifi** Please help.

Comment: `array[0][0]` is `'f'`, no? It's a string, you get the first character.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think by using array[0][0] it will get the first character in the string

Comment: What do you mean by "first value" in your question? Do you want `"from 05:04 - to 09:41"`?

Comment: i want the first value before comma like this from 05:04 - to 09:41

Comment: yes @jonrsharpe

Comment: Do you control the input? You can change it to an array of arrays if you do `[["from 05:04 - to 09:41", "train 342 SEK", ...], ...]`

Comment: Then first things first note this has absolutely nothing to do with the outer array. Research how to break a string into parts based on a character, but more broadly think about how to decompose your problem intro smaller parts you can solve separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are zero-indexed, so you can access the first element in your array with `array[0]`.

Then you can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to divide the string into an array of substrings.

> The **split()** method divides a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array. The division is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.

```js
let array = [
  "from 05:04 - to 09:41, train 342 SEK, wifi",
  "Restid 4:37 tim, 0 byten",
  "från",
  "fr.",
  "342",
  "SEK",
  "Företagspris",
  "2 klass, 2 klass Lugn, 1 klass",
  "Snabbtåg, X 2000, Tåg 522"
]

console.log(array[0].split(',')[0])
```